# Rails 3 - Loop in View - Sum up variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

If I have a loop, where each record has an "amount" field.  I would like to be able to do this...

```
<% @expense_list.each do |expense_item| %>

<% @total = @total + expense_item.amount %>
<% end %>

<%= @total %>
```

However I get this error

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because `@total` is `nil`. You need to set it to an initial number before the `each` block:

```
@total = 0
```

But if what you want to do is to sum the amount of `@expense_list`, you can use the [sum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) method too:

```
@expense_list.sum(&:amount)
```

Comment: I had tried that, .sum method but I kept getting errors, the only thing I did not do was put the & in, what is that for?

Comment: @JasonB It's using the `Symbol#to_proc`. Here's an explanation on how it works: http://iain.nl/going-crazy-with-to_proc